# How to reassign iterated reference in for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, reference, iterator

In the code below I'd expected that as we iterated through the 5 array references that we could reassign these in the loop, hence we should have five non null references at the end.

```
int[][] scores = new int[5][];
for (int[] sr : scores){
    System.out.println(sr); // 5 null entries are printed out as expected
}

for (int[] sr : scores){
    sr = new int[2]; // the 5 null references are assigned to a new array
}

for (int[] sr : scores){
    System.out.println(sr); // 5 null entries are still printed out... 
}
```

Comment: sr is a temporary variable, you can't make updates using that!

Comment: I see so sr is a copy of the reference rather than it being the actual reference. Hence redirecting the copy will not affect the original array.

Answer (score 3):

**You are NOT actually assigning objects to the `scores` array** rather you are creating a block variable inside `for` loop, the scope of the variable `sr` ends along with the `for` loop, so your code should be as follows:

```
for (int i=0;i<scores.length;i++){
    scores[i] = new int[2];//get the index and assign to scores array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sr` variable in your enhanced for loop refers to elements of your original `scores` array, but assigning values to it doesn't modify the elements of the original array.

What you are doing in your second loop is similar to :

```
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    int[] sr = scores[i];
    sr = new int[2];
}
```

which obviously doesn't modify the original array.

Use a regular for loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    scores[i] = new int[2];
}
```